# componentDidMount or componentWillMount which one I need to use

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, redux

I created a a box similar to twitter using react. I was looking at the react documentation found several component life cycles but not sure which one I should use to improve my code performance: `componentDidMount` or `componentWillMount`?

When I type something in my text box I see an update in the console printing the text box value. Can anyone help me understand which method to use and when in this case?

https://jsfiddle.net/c9zv7yf5/2/

```
class TwitterBox extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { enteredTextBoxvalue : '' };
      this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);

  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({enteredTextBoxvalue: event.target.value});   

    if((event.target.value).length > 3) {

      this.setState({className : 'wholeContainer'});
      //console.log("long characters");
    }
  }

  render() {
      return (<div>Hello {this.props.name}
              <textarea className={this.state.className}
                value={this.state.enteredTextBoxvalue}
                onChange = {this.handleChange}>
                there should be only 140 characters
            </textarea>
      </div>);
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <TwitterBox name="World" />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Comment: The official documentation actually explains quite well which "lifecycle method" to use in which situation: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html

Comment: @TomVanRompaey hey I read through the documentation but not sure when to implement...it would be great if you help me...

Answer (score 0):

componentWillMount is called right before the component gets rendered.
componentDidMount is called right after the component gets rendered.

If you need to prepare data you use componentWillMount.
componentDidMount is popularly used among sending api calls or grabbing data just right after the component renders and is highly recommended to use that.

Answer (score 0):

**componentWillMount:**

This function is called right before the component’s first render, so at first glance it appears to be a perfect place to put data fetching logic

**componentDidMount:**

Using componentDidMount makes it clear that data won’t be loaded until after the initial render. This reminds you to set up initial state properly, so you don’t end up with undefined state that causes errors.

Answer (score 0):

As part of your question is about performance you could consider also having a look at `shouldComponentUpdate` to [avoid reconciliation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/optimizing-performance.html).

componentWillMount is invoked immediately before mounting occurs. It is called before render().

componentDidMount is invoked immediately after a component is mounted.

Answer (score 0):

**componentWillMount**

- component is about to render, plays the same role as `constructor`
- there is no component in DOM yet you cannot do anything involving DOM
  manipulation
- calling `setState()` synchronously will not trigger
  re-render as the component is not rendered yet
- I would not recommend calling async `/api` requests here (technically there is no guaranty they will finish before component will be mounted, in this case the your component will not be re-rendered to apply those data)

**componentDidMount**

- component has been rendered, it already seats in the DOM
- you can perform manipulations involving DOM elements here (e.g. initialize third-party plugin)
- call async `/api` requests, etc.